# How to add django-like Formfields to a Backbone App?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm developing a single-page-app in backbone.js, that uses a lot of html forms to collect user input.
To save coding time, I'd like to have a FormField model/collection similar to [Django's Form fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/)

My requirements:

- declarative specification of the form elements and their behaviour (e.g. required true/false, events,...)
- default views/templates for all form fields (but overrideable through configuration)
- all fields belonging to a form should be stored in one Backbone.Collection for easier field retrieval
- validation of the entire form or individual elements

Here is what my simple form field implementation might look like:

```
 FormField = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function (attributes, options){
        //TODO: initialize form field according to type,
        // i.e. set up correct view, validation etc.
    }
    defaults: {
        type: "TextField",
        label: "Unknown Label",
        required: false,
    }
});
FormFields = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: FormField})

MyPlugin = new PluginModel({
    //TODO: render a form with these config options within the edit view of the PluginModel
    config: FormFields([
        {type: "TextField", id:"store_name", label: "Name of Store", required: true},
        {type: "SelectField", id:"store_type", label: "Type of Store", required: true, choices: ['local','http']},
    ]),
    //runs after user "submits" form
    run: function (){
        if this.config.isValid(){

        }
    }
});
```

However, I ran into the following issues:

- A `Backbone.Collection` can only host Models of the same type. What is the best way to store different form fields in one collection? 
  (My approach is to use just one `FormField` class, all differentiation happens based on the formfield type in the initialize() method, but this seems a bit messy to me)
- How can i setup the correct view for each FormField instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really found of using model to dictate UI elements...

Leave your model clean. Only data that goes in and out of your application through your backend. Your validation lives in your model (see backbone documentation for the validation method). Your model contains all the fields that you will show up on your view.

Now you need information on those field (what you call FormFields). They do not need to be a backbone model and they do not need to be inserted in a backbone collection. A plain javascript object and array would suffice. Add this information to your model as you extend it (array of field descriptions).

Instantiate your generic form view from your model and create the form using the field descriptions. Listen for change events on the inputs, selects, textareas and update your model. If a validation error shows up, an "error" event will be triggered on the model and you can react on your view (show the error).

Comment: Don't get me wrong... I just wanted to follow the DRY principle with my FormField model. Form creation/validation/serialisation is a cross-cutting-concern in my app... many different models need this functionality, so I thought this was the best way to implement it. About the formfield collection: I need a way to conveniently access the serialized form field values in my model, e.g. `form.get('field_id').get('value')` and a backbone collection seemed perfect for that.

Comment: So is a javascript object: form.field_name.value ... If you do not need eventing from the backbone collection and model, it is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

I've ported Django's forms library to JavaScript as [newforms](https://github.com/insin/newforms) - it's a pretty direct port at the moment, which can create form fields as DOM elements or HTML, but doesn't do any binding to the DOM or events yet.

I'm not familiar with Backbone.js, but if it makes the task easier, I'd be interested to hear about how it does so. I'd rather provide useful helpers which keep it open for people to set up binding as they wish rather than forcing a particular pattern of usage and reinventing a bunch of wheels in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with backbone-forms.js https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms